# The formula expression is invalid: Incorrect number of parameters for function 'IF()'. Expected 3, received 2

Tags: visual-workflow, formula, parameters, function

Receiving an error when trying to save the below formula. The requirement is that if the first variable is empty, to retrieve the value for the second variable.

```
IF({!var_EmailAddress_1} = "",{!var_EmailAddress_2})
```

Comment: The error is extremely clear here.

Answer (score 1):

The syntax for IF() should contain three values as below.

```
IF(logical_test, value_if_true, value_if_false).
```

In your Formula you have given logical_test and value_if_true but you missed value_if_false which means if the emailaddress1 is not null then what should be the value it can be something as below. I am making the value as null if the EmailAddress1 is not null.

```
IF({!var_EmailAddress_1} = "",{!var_EmailAddress_2},'')
```

Comment: Thank you, Sai for the speedy review! is it better to use "BLANK" or "EMPTY" in this case if we are evaluating whether the variable is null?